# Android ListView Scroll Position in Pixel Detect

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to detect the number of pixel on the listview that the user has scrolled. and at the same time, i can base on the number of pixel have been scrolled and i display a textview with the pixel that have been scrolled.

would appreciate your answer .thanks!!

justicepenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808387/android-getting-exact-scroll-position-in-listview/13415273#13415273).

```
View.getScrollY()
```

is a method inherited from View, and the doc says:

> Return the scrolled top position of this view. This is the top edge of the displayed part of your view.

Therefore for full screen lists it will always return 0.

Comment: @justicepenny care to share your solution?

Answer (score 1):

[`View.getScrollY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollY%28%29) should be helpful. That should give you the scroll position that you're looking for.