# ListView onScrollChanged always returns 0

Tags: android, android-listview

I created a class that extends `ListView` so that I can override `onScrollChanged` so that I can tell is the list has been scrolled up or down. However everytime it gets called, all the values are 0.

Doing this for a regular `ScrollView` returns me the values I am looking for so does this not work the same as ScrollView?

here is my wrapper class

```
public class ImageScrollView extends ListView {

    OnScrollChangedListener listener;

    public interface OnScrollChangedListener{
        public void onScrollChangedListener(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }

    public ImageScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ImageScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt){

        if(listener != null){
            listener.onScrollChangedListener(l,t,oldl,oldt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, you should use "AbsListView.OnScrollListener" instead of implementing it explicitly. So you just need to implement it next to your class name. & implement same code inside those overridden methods.

Answer (score 3):

For `listview`, `onScrollChanged` always returns all values `0`, so does `getScrollY()` etc, apparently. Depending on what you need, you'll have to implement `onScrollListener` interface, which will get called back thru `onScroll` and `onScrollStateChanged`.
None of these functions will give you the actual scroll value, for that you'll have to compute it,

for instance in

```
onScroll(AbsListView list ...)
{ 
    View c = list.getChildAt(0);

    if (c == null) {
        return;
    }

    //assuming all list items have same height
    int scrolly = -c.getTop() + list.getPaddingTop() + list.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight(); 

    // some code
}
```

see the following post from which i got most answers
[Android getting exact scroll position in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808387/android-getting-exact-scroll-position-in-listview)

Comment: what if the listview has headers?