# Exact y-Position of an Element in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have an onClickListener on a button inside my listView elements, which needs to show a popup under itsself.

The way I tried to achieve it was to simply use `v.getBottom()` inside the onClickListener. However this would not return the correct position of the clicked button.

I then tried to get the position by calculating the yPosition of the listItem using this answer to get the exact scroll position: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10808454/3963566

```
View c = listView.getChildAt(0);
int yPosition = (int) listView.getChildAt(position).getBottom() - (-c.getTop() + listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight());
popupWindow.showAtLocation(listView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, yPosition);
```

Adapter Code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result, parent, false);
    listView = (ListView) parent;
    mainContainer = (LinearLayout) parent.getParent().getParent().getParent();

    ibEmployment = (SquareImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ib_employment);
    ibEmployment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showEmploymentPopup(v, position);
        }
    });
}

private void showEmploymentPopup(View v, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_categories,null);
    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 400, 600, true);
    // display the popup in the center
    pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.TOP, 0, v.getTop() + v.getMeasuredHeight() + 300);
    initializeCategoriesList(position);
    setCertificateStatus(position);
    pw.showAsDropDown(v);
}
```

But the yPosition is only accurate for the first two list items as long as the list was not scrolled.

Comment: Did you tried passing childview instead of listview inside showAtLocation method to show popup.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH yes. then the popup is always shown at the top of the listView

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with Listview itemview.

Create method for showing popupwindow in adaper class.

```
 private void initiatePopupWindow(View v) {
    try {
        //We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater, use the context of this activity
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,null);
        // create a 300px width and 470px height PopupWindow
        pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 400, 600, true);
        // display the popup in the center
        pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.TOP, 0, v.getTop() + v.getMeasuredHeight() + 300); //300 is haif of popwindow height to place popupwindow top line below item bottomline.
        TextView mResultText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.result_txt);
        Button cancelButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pw.dismiss();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And add click event to view in item in listview.

```
 textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                initiatePopupWindow(itemView);//itemview is your entire row view of listview.
            }
```

**Output**

[image]

Hope it helps.!

Comment: Unfortuantely this doesn't work as well. The popup is alwas shown at the top of the listView

Comment: Did you pass your itemview in arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162085/discussion-between-mohamed-mohaideen-ah-and-max90).

Answer (score 0):

`listView.getChildAt(position)` may be wrong because you are trying to access adapter position, while the number of child view of a listview may smaller than adapter count.
I think you may want to try simpler way:

```
    yourBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
        @Override    
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int positions[] = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(positions);
            // Use positions for calculation
            // ...

        }
    });
```